# How can I prevent Supervisor to run at startup?

Tags: 13.10

I'm using the very useful [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/).  But I'd like to prevent it from running when I start ubuntu: is it possible ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it's a service (daemon) install rcconf:

```
sudo apt-get install rcconf
```

And then, run it and disable supervisor with it (uncheck its corresponding box, and accept):

```
sudo rcconf
```

Whenever you want to run it manually you can use the command:

```
sudo service supervidor start

sudo service supervidor stop
```

Comment: Haaa, great, thanks: I wasn't sure all services were managed the exact same way.  Perhaps should I extend my question to *How can I prevent a service to run at startup* ?

Comment: There's plenty of such question, so yours would probably marked as duplicated. You can manage a lot of services with rcconf, just be sure you find out first what they do before you disable something critical. Glad it helped :)

Comment: Oh, ok.  Anyway `rcconf` is a great tool, thanks a lot !

Comment: Doesn't `rcconf` work only with SistemV-init style files? Probably in this case `supervisor` is in that category (otherwise it wouldn't work), but take into account that most of Ubuntu "services" are managed by upstart (see @drc's answer)

Comment: To be honest I don't really know, but I would be really interested if you know some upstart manager equivalent to rcconf, I think bum (boot up manager) is one of them, but may it be a command line equivalent? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

There's probably a file for it in `/etc/init/`, probably called `supervisord.conf` which instructs upstart to start `supervisord` on boot.

The file will have the start conditions some close to the top, looking somewhat like this (taken from lightdm's init file):

```
start on ((filesystem
           and runlevel [!06]
           and started dbus
           and plymouth-ready)
          or runlevel PREVLEVEL=S)
```

**Update**: As mentioned in the comments, the usual way of disabling an upstart service is creating an override file for that service by issuing the following command:

`echo 'manual' | sudo tee /etc/init/supervisord.override`

You could also comment those lines using `#` and `supervisord` won't start automatically, but changes like that might be overwritten by a future update.

If there is no such file, supervisor might be using old, init-style configs in /etc/init.d/. If that's the case, you can disable it by running

`update-rc.d -f supervisord remove`

Comment: Correct, although the "standard" way to locally disable services at startup for upstart is `sudo bash -c "echo 'manual' >> /etc/init/supervisord.override"` (so that it will not be re-enabled by updates or similar events).

Comment: You're correct, must have slipped my mind. I'll update my post accordingly.